# AlarmManager start service hourly every hour to download files (. Zip) entering timeout

Tags: android

I have a service that runs every hour by a shot in my AlarmManager startAPP.class (main activity) in onCreate, as follows:

```
Intent it = new Intent("SINC");
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(StartAPP.this, 0, it, 0);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, inicio);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, repetir, p);
```

Everything ok. The service is triggered exactly as it should. But how is that a download is done execution is somewhat slow (minutes) 1 or 2. And this time the android triggers a dialog stating that the application stopped responding and asks if I want to close or wait.

How do I get this service does not display this message (dialog). Because from what I read services are used for processing time consuming and downloading files.

The service extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public class Sinc extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Note: if I tell the dialog I want to wait, the whole service process is successfully completed. (all files are downloaded)

Thanks

Comment: If you have used my answer and found it acceptable, please click the check mark indicating that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your Sinc class inherit from IntentService instead of BroadcastReceiver and modify your PendingIntent to be a service intent instead of a broadcast intent.